# WCF Async method works on Windows 7 host, but throws signature Exception on XP machine

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, asynchronous

My code (target framework 4.0, x86 architecture) works on several *Windows 7* machines (both client and server) but throws an `Invalid Async Begin method signature` Exception on *Windows Xp* (same .NET framework version) specifying that a method requires `IAsyncResult` as result type and a callback method.

Actually, my methods use successfully `Task<GenericType>` as return type and I'm wondering why it fails only on XP hosts.

Example of service contract:

```
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    Task<GetServerConfigurationResult> GetServerConfigurationAsync(string clientID);
```

**Note**: I hope there's a smarter solution than refactoring.